# Sharing views among multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

I am not able to share views among multiple controllers in Ruby ob Rails application.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the view you are trying to render the other view

```
abc - The name of the folder in which the other view exists (views/abc/view_name.html.erb)
xyz - The name of the view
```

---

```
<%= render :template "abc/xyz" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even use partials or explicitly render another template in controller's action.eg: -

```
def UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @records = User.all
    render '/products/index' # instead of user's index i rendered product's index template
  end

end
```